# Find all such mappings where $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $B=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $f:A \to B$ is an injective mapping such that $f(i) \neq i ~\forall i=1,2,3,4$.

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Fund all such mappings where $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $B=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $f:A \to B$ is an injective mapping such that $f(i) \neq i ~\forall i=1,2,3,4$.

I'm thinking about using the principle of inclusion and exclusion but I'm somewhat not sure how to do that. I think I'm getting lots of cases. Basically, I'm considering all possible values $i$ (for $1\leq i \leq 4$) can map to and that's basically $5$ for each $i$ since $f(i)\neq i$. After that, we will use PIE to rule out the cases when the condition $f(1)\neq f(2)\neq f(3)\neq f(4)$ isn't satisfied. But I think that's a bit of a big thing. Please continue from here; I'm not exactly getting to the destination.

Also, if some nice bijection exists, it would be quite appreciated.

Comment: As you suggest, I expect Inclusion-Exclusion is easiest.  Count the injections without further constraints.  Then subtract those in which one specified value is fixed.  Then add those in which two specified values are fixed, and so on.

Comment: How can you have a bijection when $|A| ≠|B|$?

Comment: @BDN I meant, a bijection from this idea to some other idea. Like, we use stars and bars to calculate the number of integer solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $E$ be the set of injective mappings, and let $E_i$ be the set of injective mappings where $f(i)=i$. Then, letting $AB$ denote $A\cap B$,
$$
\text{#}\{f:\forall i\;f(i)\neq i\}=|E|-\sum_i|E_i|+\sum_{i<j}|E_iE_j|-\sum_{i<j<k}|E_iE_jE_k|+|E_1E_2E_3E_4|
$$
Now,
$$
\begin{aligned}
|E|&=6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3,  \\
|E_i|&=5\cdot 4\cdot 3,&\\
|E_iE_j|&=4\cdot 3,&
\end{aligned}
$$
etc.